# How do I make docker-compose on OS X work with a Play app?

Tags: macos, playframework, sbt, docker, boot2docker

I am trying to run a Dockerized [Play app](https://github.com/aknuds1/play-docker-example) on OS X via [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) 1.1.0/[boot2docker](http://boot2docker.io/) 1.5.0. However, it doesn't really, well, play (pardon the pun)...

The problem is that the app must run with a pseudo TTY (provided by Docker), and this makes boot2docker hang while trying to attach.

I run the app, through `docker-compose up`, and it hangs as shown below:

```
> docker-compose up
Recreating exampleapp_web_1...
Attaching to exampleapp_web_1
```

However, if I run the app directly, without docker-compose, it works:

```
> docker rm exampleapp_web_1 ; docker run -p 9000:9000 -ti --name exampleapp_web_1 -v `pwd`:/code -v `pwd`/.docker_home:/root exampleapp_web
[info] Loading project definition from /code/project
[info] Set current project to example-app (in build file:/code/)

--- (Running the application, auto-reloading is enabled) ---

[info] play - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000

(Server started, use Ctrl+D to stop and go back to the console...)
```

How do I make docker-compose work in my scenario?

## docker-compose.yml

```
web:
  build: .
  command: run
  ports:
    - "9000:9000"
  volumes:
    - .:/code
    - .docker_home:/root
  stdin_open: true
  tty: true
```

## Dockerfile

```
FROM aknudsen/play-with-node
MAINTAINER Arve Knudsen <arve.knudsen@gmail.com>

COPY ./ /code
WORKDIR /code

EXPOSE 9000

ENTRYPOINT ["sbt"]
CMD ["run"]
```

## Verbose output from `docker-compose up`

```
> docker-compose --verbose up
Compose version 1.1.0
Docker base_url: https://192.168.59.103:2376
Docker version: KernelVersion=3.18.5-tinycore64, Arch=amd64, ApiVersion=1.17, Version=1.5.0, GitCommit=a8a31ef, Os=linux, GoVersion=go1.4.1
docker containers <- (all=True)
docker containers -> (list with 3 items)
Creating exampleapp_web_1...
docker containers <- (all=True)
docker containers -> (list with 3 items)
docker images <- (name=u'exampleapp_web')
docker images -> (list with 1 items)
docker create_container <- (tty=True, name=u'exampleapp_web_1', image=u'exampleapp_web', stdin_open=True, environment={}, command='run', volumes={u'/code': {}, u'/root': {}}, detach=False, ports=[u'9000'])
docker create_container -> {u'Id': u'dc0ebc7e34ea8793023a968725ab696e1a3d60341105e84e81ace776952f55d8',
 u'Warnings': None}
docker inspect_container <- (u'dc0ebc7e34ea8793023a968725ab696e1a3d60341105e84e81ace776952f55d8')
docker inspect_container -> {u'AppArmorProfile': u'',
 u'Args': [u'run'],
 u'Config': {u'AttachStderr': True,
             u'AttachStdin': True,
             u'AttachStdout': True,
             u'Cmd': [u'run'],
             u'CpuShares': 0,
             u'Cpuset': u'',
             u'Domainname': u'',
             u'Entrypoint': [u'sbt'],
...
docker start <- (u'dc0ebc7e34ea8793023a968725ab696e1a3d60341105e84e81ace776952f55d8', links=[], cap_add=None, restart_policy=None, dns_search=None, network_mode=u'bridge', binds={u'/Users/arve/Projects/example-app/.docker_home': {u'bind': u'/root', u'ro': False}, u'/Users/arve/Projects/example-app': {u'bind': u'/code', u'ro': False}}, dns=None, volumes_from=[], port_bindings={u'9000': [u'9000']}, cap_drop=None, privileged=False)
docker start -> None
docker containers <- (all=False)
docker containers -> (list with 2 items)
Attaching to exampleapp_web_1
docker attach <- (u'dc0ebc7e34ea8793023a968725ab696e1a3d60341105e84e81ace776952f55d8', stderr=1, logs=1, stream=1, stdout=1)
docker attach -> <generator object _multiplexed_response_stream_helper at 0x1062db2d0>
```

## Log of Docker container

```
> docker logs exampleapp_web_1
[info] Loading project definition from /code/project
[info] Set current project to example-app (in build file:/code/)

--- (Running the application, auto-reloading is enabled) ---

[info] play - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000

(Server started, use Ctrl+D to stop and go back to the console...)
```

## GitHub Issue

There's a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1229) that seems to be describing this very problem.

Comment: can you run compose in verbose mode. also can you include your docker log?

Comment: @booyaa Included both now, thanks.

Comment: odd seeing no errors at all , will have to do some testing, presumably a successful test is if you can reach the site on http://b2d-ip:9000/ using ```docker-compose```?

Comment: @booyaa I'm not surprised this is happening, I guessed the hang was due to capturing streams from Docker and in turn its guest application. I found an issue on GitHub that looks similar: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1229.

Answer (score 1):

see this url https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ProductionConfiguration

steps to run application in production

1) in project folder, run $sbt dist
2) execute this command from project root  ./target/universal/your-app-name -javaArguments ...

in docker-compose

```
web:
build: .
command: sbt dist && ./target/universal/app-name -JavaArguments
ports:
  - "9000:9000"
volumes:
  - .:/code
  - .docker_home:/root
stdin_open: true
tty: true
```